# Requisições em AJAX funciona no WebView?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Tenho o seguinte `WebView`:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
myWebView.loadUrl('http://192.168.0.4:8080/map/index.html?value_id=666');
```

Dentro do `index.html` possui um mapa do Google, requisitado através do Google Maps API, no qual contém algumas requisições em AJAX(`GET`,`POST`, em um *server local*), buscando alguns [*markers*](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker?hl=pt-br) no banco de dados. No browser funciona normalmente, porém dentro do aplicativo não funciona. Minha suspeita é que não está funcionando essas requisições por não está aparecendo os marcadores no mapa. Aí veio a dúvida:

- Requisições em AJAX funciona no Webview? Se sim, oque deixei de definir no WebView para que funcione corretamente? Se não, há uma alternativa viável de contornar isso ?

Vejam os testes

**No *browser*:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**No *app*:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

O problema que você deve estar tendo é com [cors](/questions/tagged/cors), não tem como desabilitar a segurança no `webView` para evitar estes problemas, se você tiver acesso a API então deve adicionar o header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Se não tiver acesso aos códigos back-end da API então o que você pode fazer é criar uma especie de *proxy* para poder reescrever os *headers*

Então creio que conforme esta [resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42544537/1518921) pode fazer algo semelhante:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    ...

    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        final String method = request.getMethod();
        final String url = request.getUrl().toString();

        Log.d(TAG, "processRequest: " + url + " method " + method);

        String ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
        String mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod(method);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            Map<String, String> responseHeaders = convertResponseHeaders(conn.getHeaderFields());

            //Permite o CORS
            responseHeaders.put("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            //Permite ajustar o content-type nas requisições ajax
            responseHeaders.put("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");

            return new WebResourceResponse(
                mime,
                conn.getContentEncoding(),
                conn.getResponseCode(),
                conn.getResponseMessage(),
                responseHeaders,
                conn.getInputStream()
            );

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "shouldInterceptRequest: " + e);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

> Não testei ainda mas a resposta é usar mesmo `shouldInterceptRequest` se não tiver acesso ao servers-side da API